# Assetic stylesheets in Symfony

Tags: css, symfony, twig, assetic

I have been trying to figure out how to get assetic working with my CSS sources but am having no luck. Two articles I've been tyring to cross-reference are [combining and minimising ccs files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/php.html#combining-and-minimizing-css-files-and-compiling-scss-files) and [assetic asset management](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html). However, the hybrid I've ended up with is the below which isn't working:

```
    {% stylesheets filter="scssphp" output="css/my.css"
        "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
        "bundles/app/css/*"
    %}

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

However, when I try running (in Dev) I get an error saying:

> Unexpected token "name" of value "rel" in base.html.twig at line 19

PS I have installed `leafo` and `jsqueeze` (I have javascripts to do figure out next) with:

```
$ composer require leafo/scssphp
$ composer require patchwork/jsqueeze:"~1.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have here an error in your code:

```
{% stylesheets filter="scssphp" output="css/my.css"
    "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
    "bundles/app/css/*"
%}
```

in every line you have a file that should be rendered. In the second line you have added `rel` and `type`. you have to delete that both parameters otherwise its an option for `stylesheets`. If you delete them it should work.

Comment: Great thank you very much.... just in case anyone else has the same problem I also had to remove the `type=` and `>` on the same line